# What is the difference between "console.printf" and "System.out.println"?

Tags: java

What can "import java.io Console" allow me to do? I cannot figure out why you would set up a Console object.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369731/java-console-applications-is-system-out-still-the-way-to-go

Comment: @Apolozeus No, It's not a duplicate with that. Because this is just questioning the `Console.printf()` properties and why it's there in the JRE Library.

Answer (score 0):

The class console will only work in the console.
 If you are not using the console(any other standard output other than console) you should use System.out.print.

And you have to create instance of Console but not for System.out.print

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "other standard output"?

Comment: Like the Command Prompt or the console of the IDE you're using.