# console.writeline and System.out.println

Tags: java, io

What exactly is the technical difference between `console.writeline` and `System.out.println`? 
I know that `System.out.println` writes to standard output but is this not the same thing as the console?

I do not fully understand the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) for `console.writeline`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369731/java-console-applications-is-system-out-still-the-way-to-go

Comment: also console.writeline is not a java method (it is .net)... but I understand what you're asking :)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Here are the primary differences between using [`System.out`/`.err`/`.in`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) and [`System.console()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console()):

- `System.console()` returns null if your application is not run in a terminal ([though you can handle this in your application](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html))
- `System.console()` provides methods for reading password without echoing characters
- `System.out` and `System.err` use the default platform encoding, while the `Console` class output methods use the console encoding

This latter behaviour may not be immediately obvious, but code like this can demonstrate the difference:

```
public class ConsoleDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] data = { "\u250C\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2510", 
        "\u2502Hello\u2502",
        "\u2514\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2500\u2518" };
    for (String s : data) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
    for (String s : data) {
      System.console().writer().println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

On my Windows XP which has a system encoding of windows-1252 and a default console encoding of IBM850, this code will write:

```
???????
?Hello?
???????
┌─────┐
│Hello│
└─────┘
```

Note that this behaviour depends on the console encoding being set to a different encoding to the system encoding. This is the default behaviour on Windows for a bunch of historical reasons.

Comment: Can you get an example of not running in a terminal?

Comment: @Richard, if you hit run from an IDE, or if you launch an executable jar from a GUI.

Comment: what to import?

Answer (score 16):

They're essentially the same, if your program is run from an interactive prompt and you haven't redirected stdin or stdout:

```
public class ConsoleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Console is: " + System.console());
    }
}
```

results in:

```
$ java ConsoleTest
Console is: java.io.Console@2747ee05
$ java ConsoleTest </dev/null
Console is: null
$ java ConsoleTest | cat
Console is: null
```

The reason `Console` exists is to provide features that are useful in the specific case that you're being run from an interactive command line:

- secure password entry (hard to do cross-platform)
- synchronisation (multiple threads can prompt for input and `Console` will queue them up nicely, whereas if you used System.in/out then all of the prompts would appear simultaneously).

Notice above that redirecting even *one* of the streams results in `System.console()` returning `null`; another irritation is that there's often no `Console` object available when spawned from another program such as Eclipse or Maven.

Comment: what to import?

Answer (score 11):

First I am afraid your question contains a little mistake. There is not method writeline in class Console. Instead class Console provides method writer() that returns PrintWriter. This print writer has println().

Now what is the difference between

```
System.console().writer().println("hello from console");
```

and

```
System.out.println("hello system out");
```

If you run your application from command line I think there is no difference. But if console is unavailable System.console() returns null while System.out still exists. This may happen if you invoke your application and perform redirect of STDOUT to file.

Here is an example I have just implemented.

```
import java.io.Console;


public class TestConsole {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();
        System.out.println("console=" + console);
        console.writer().println("hello from console");
    }
}
```

When I ran the application from command prompt I got the following:

```
$ java TestConsole
console=java.io.Console@93dcd
hello from console
```

but when I redirected the STDOUT to file...

```
$ java TestConsole >/tmp/test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at TestConsole.main(TestConsole.java:8)
```

Line 8 is `console.writer().println()`.

Here is the content of /tmp/test

```
console=null
```

I hope my explanations help.

Comment: To cause code to show up as code blocks, indent each line with four spaces. (I've just done that for you, though.)

Comment: There is, however, a Console.printf, and a Console.format, both of which write directly, without needing to extract the intervening PrintWriter. Weird :)

Answer (score 4):

There's no `Console.writeline` in Java. Its in .NET.

Console and standard out are not same. If you read the Javadoc page you [mentioned](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html), you will see that an application can have access to a console only if it is invoked from the command line and the output is not redirected like this

```
java -jar MyApp.jar > MyApp.log
```

Other such cases are covered in SimonJ's answer, though he missed out on the point that there's no `Console.writeline`.

Comment: Yup - I figured ziggy's compiler (or the Javadocs) could do that job for me :)

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` references an instance of PrintStream.

`System.console.writer` references an instance of PrintWriter.

See [System.out.println vs PrintWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722120/system-out-println-vs-printwriter)

Comment: what to import?