# An application to get Userinput and to run commands background in windows

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, runtime, processbuilder

I want to create one standalone executable file which accepts some user input and it should use those inputs as arguments to run a command at CMD as background process. For GUI i thought of using swings and to run cmd batch file  . Is it possible to merge java files and batch file  to form an exe.? or i should go for someother scripting languages to execute command at background process and someother programming languages for UI design ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005378/console-writeline-and-system-out-println) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could do this all in Java.  As you mentioned, you could use Swing to read in the user input.  Instead of trying to get ahold of the input data from a separate batch file, you could just use Java's [`Runtime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class to [execute a command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) using the inputs as arguments.

And, if you need this all to run from an executable, you could use a utility like [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) to wrap the Java application.

Comment: thanks for your reply. let me make my question clear. for ex: if i have a command like ( a.exe -b id <arg1> -f <arg2> ) here a.exe, -b id -f were default. arg1 and arg2 should be supplied from user input to make complete command and i want to execute this as background process. is this possible from Runtime class?? In unix & is used o run background process . what about windows machines then?