# System.out.println vs PrintWriter

Tags: java, io, printwriter, printstream

Is there a difference in using these two?  When would you use one over the other?

```
System.out.println(result);
```

versus

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
out.println(result);
out.flush();
```

Comment: One's a PringStream and the other's a PrintWriter. PrintStreams can allow more flexibility with encoding. I'm guessing that some system encodings are used, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `System.out` is a [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) and `PrintWriter` is ... a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

Comment: `PrintWriter` is also about twice as fast for printing text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main difference is that [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html) and the other one is a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html). Essentially, `PrintStream` should be used to write a stream of *bytes*, while `PrintWriter` should be used to write a stream of *characters* (and thus it deals with character encodings and such).

For most use cases, there is no difference.

Answer (score 5):

`System.out` is instance of `PrintStream`

So your question narrows down to `PrintStream` vs `PrintWriter`

- All characters printed by a `PrintStream` are converted into bytes using the platform's default character encoding. (Syso writes out directly to system output/console)
- The `PrintWriter` class should be used in situations that require writing characters rather than bytes.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using PrintWriter if you have to print more than 10^3 lines in one go.
[image: Performace comparison up to 10^5]
[image: Performace comparison up to 10^7]

I got this by running these snippets 3 times each for n=10^1 to 10^7 and then taking mean of there execution time.

```
class Sprint{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=10000000;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}

import java.io.*;
class Pprint{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int n=10000000;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            out.println(i);
        }
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a slight difference. `out.println()` is short and is used in JSP while `PrintWriter` is used in servlets. `out.println()` is also derived from PrintWriter.