# what is the difference between console.println and system.out.format

Tags: java, between, difference

Hey guys i have seen many ways in java to do the same things.

Please tell me what is the difference between `console.println` or `console.readLine` and `system.out.format` whichever is the closest match.

Comment: Might be it is a difference between std.io and console? This is impossible to understand none of them has `println` method (tell my `hello` to Delphi). It seems to be rather duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005378/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are asking difference between

`System.console.write` and `System.out.println`

Here are few differences between System.console.write and System.out.println

- System.console() returns null if your application is not run in a
  terminal (though you can handle this in your application)
- System.console() provides methods for reading password without
  echoing characters
- System.out and System.err use the default platform encoding, while
  the Console class output methods use the console encoding