# Underline ANSI string not working as planned (In Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to underline a certain piece of text, however it is not outputting what I had expected.

```
String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
String ANSI_UNDERLINE = "\u001B[4m";
String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";

System.out.print(ANSI_UNDERLINE + "HelloWorld" + ANSI_RESET);
```

This does not output an underlined "HelloWorld", however it does output red text if I replace ANSI_UNDERLINE with ANSI_RED.

Does anyone have an explanation as to why it is not outputting underlined text in the console?

Comment: are you asking for GUI? bcuz you want this to work in console it isnt possible

Comment: I just ran your code in console, it printed with underline and red

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005378/console-writeline-and-system-out-println

Comment: Not for GUI, for the console output. Just to clarify, are you saying it is impossible to underline, or impossible to colour or underline in the console?